# SQL statement for unique rows

Tags: mysql, database

I am attempting to extract information from a table that holds account numbers, phone numbers, and emails. However, I'm not sure what whoever designed this table was thinking. The table is set up like this.

AccountID | PhoneType | PhoneNumber

Now you might be asking where are the emails stored. They are stored under phone number. An example of this database.

```
AccountID | PhoneType | PhoneNumber
123456        WORK        111-1111
123456        MOBILE      111-4567
123456        EMAIL     exampleemail@email.com
222222        EMAIL      stupid@table.com
```

I'm not sure how to do this as I have just a rudimentary knowledge of SQL. We would ideally want things like:

```
AccountID | WorkPhone | MobilePhone | Email
123456       111-1111    111-4567     example@email.com
222222                                stupid@table.com
```

What is a good way to go about doing this? I've tried a couple IF statements but nothing that gets me to what I would want.

Comment: are there only 3 distinct PhoneTypes?

Comment: There are FAX, 800, and HOME. Also I just realized there is just 'email' also. You know... without caps. I figured if somebody could help me with just the couple that are there I could adapt and do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just building on CodeLikeBeaker's response.

Distinct won't do it  as each record is unique when pivoted using the case.  However by using a max() aggregate on each case and a group by we can combine the records.

```
SELECT AccountId
     , max(CASE WHEN PhoneType = 'WorkPhone' THEN PhoneNumber END) AS 'WorkPhone'
     , max(CASE WHEN PhoneType = 'MobilePhone' THEN PhoneNumber END) AS 'MobilePhone'
     , max(CASE WHEN PhoneType = 'Email' THEN PhoneNumber END) AS 'Email'
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY accountID
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would work. If you had more phone types, this could get long:

**Edit:** Based on xQbert's response, he was correct. You need to add a group by on Account ID, otherwise you will still get multiple rows.

```
SELECT
    AccountId
    , MAX(CASE WHEN PhoneType = 'WorkPhone' THEN
        PhoneNumber
      ELSE
        NULL
    END) AS 'WorkPhone'
    , MAX(CASE WHEN PhoneType = 'MobilePhone' THEN
        PhoneNumber
      ELSE
        NULL
    END) AS 'MobilePhone'
    , MAX(CASE WHEN PhoneType = 'Email' THEN
        PhoneNumber
      ELSE
        NULL
    END) AS 'Email'
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY AccountId
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the rows unique? Executing this gave me 3 separate rows of an account that had all 3 but had 3 separate rows.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to add the `DISTINCT` keyword before Account Id

Comment: No you'd need to max the case statements and group by accountID... Distinct won't do it.  since there are 3 records in myTable for a single account, 3 records will be in the result unless group or distinct is used.  Since each record is distinct with the null placements; no records would be removed.  Thus the max and group by is needed instead of distinct.

Answer (score -1):

If phone types are limited known set, then simply Join. Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.AccountId,
       wp.PhoneNumber as WorkPhone,
       mp.PhoneNumber as MobilePhone,
       em.PhoneNumber as Email
    FROM MyTable As a
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT AccountId, PhoneNumber FROM MyTable
               WHERE PhoneType = 'WORK') As wp
         ON a.AccountId = wp.AccountId
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT AccountId, PhoneNumber FROM MyTable
               WHERE PhoneType = 'MOBILE') As mp
         ON a.AccountId = mp.AccountId
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT AccountId, PhoneNumber FROM MyTable
               WHERE PhoneType = 'EMAIL') As em
         ON a.AccountId = em.AccountId
```

Comment: I think this would be inefficient due to the fact you are querying the table for each join. Also if you look at the profiler for this query you get tons more executions then you would if you did a case statement.

Comment: It is depend on table size and query size. I agree case statement have less loops. however the argument is if dataset is not too big after the first scan the data is in cache and the following loop through are pretty quick.

Depend on situation. I prefer this one if situation allows because this one is easier to read :)

Comment: Then I would suggest doing a standard `LEFT JOIN` on the same table with a double `ON` clause versus a `LEFT JOIN (SELECT)`. Even then you will have more executions than a single query, but it will be far less processing than what you have.

Comment: Unfortunately the source table has about 500,000 rows and I'm already joining it with 2 other tables so this solution I can't really use.

Comment: It is interesting to see the down-vote. This is an very valid solution.  Actually a pretty common solution, as I said, under certain situations. I know in some cases it is not preferred. Not accepting is fine, but down-vote a friendly option is just ...